# Xamarin.Forms ImageButton Image Padding

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, imagebutton

How to make paddings for the source image inside image button?

**UPDATE:**

```xaml
<ImageButton Source="cell_arrow_right.png" IsVisible="{Binding IsNotLeaf}"
                     VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                     WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" Aspect="Fill"
                     Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked" Margin="0, 0, 15, 0"
                     BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Accent" 
                     BorderWidth="1" Scale="0.9" CornerRadius="5" />
```

I tried to use `Padding`, not working.. It just moves the source image. Also I tried to edit `margin` - still no result.
Now I've just edited the image itself, made it with paddings. But that's bad decision..(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is actually `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions`, both are set to `Center`, which will position the `ImageButton` in the center of it's containing element.

Try removing them completely (they default to `HorizontalOptions=Fill`, same for vertical).  Or you could try:

```xaml
<ImageButton VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="10" />
```

This will give a margin of 10 around the `ImageButton` and position the image at the start of its containing element (horizontally and vertically, ie Top and Left).

Padding represents the distance between an element and it's child elements.

Margin represents the distance between an element and adjacent elements.

There is a good guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding).